Error install Zabbix Agent 6.4 on Windows
I have a Windows 10 in which until ten days ago I had a zabbix agent 6.4 installed and configured correctly. But one day I decided to uninstall it because of personal reasons using Control Panel->Programs and features-> remove, and everything worked right.
The problem comes now that I want to install it again on the same machine and I have the following error and the time of executing the zabbix agent installer:

I have checked the Programs and features and the zabbix agent is not here any more.
How can I solve this problem in order to have the zabbix agent installed again?

run the services.msc program, is the Zabbix Agent service still installed?

Thank you very much for your response. Yes. I can confirm you that the Zabbix agent service is still there, despite of being stopped and impossible to run.

so stop and remove that service first. you can either use zabbix_agentd.exe –uninstall or  msiexec /uninstall zabbix_agent....msi /qn
